# Probability with binomial model of 3 events

Tags: probability

If one person will guess exactly $7$ correct answers, we have a binomial model with $k=7$ successes and $n=10$ trials with probability $p$. So for the first one, the probability will be $binopdf(7,10,0.8)=0.2013$, for the second is $0.057$ and for the third is $0.25$. Now from here, would it be fine to add them, to answer the exercise?

Comment: I do not think it is correct to post again the same question MSE closed 3 days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904569/probability-in-trivia-game. Anyway see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now from here, would it be fine to add them, to answer the exercise?

Let's make the following modifications: the total questions are 2 and for each contestant the probability to guess correct answer is 0.5.  Find the probability that one contestant (any one) answers exactly 1 question correctly, while the other two give any other number of correct answers.

The probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ for any partecipant...do you think you can add

$$\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}=150\%$$

??

---

Using the probabilities you calculated, the answer is

$$0.2013(1-0.057)(1-0.25)+0.057(1-0.2013)(1-0.25)+0.25(1-0.2013)(1-0.057)$$

Comment: Well, I see you can't add them, but what should you do? It's not a conditional probability

Comment: @tyuiop: adding the 3 probabilities you double count 3times the event that any contestand answer exactly 7 questions on 10. See my edits